# How to Sort Date in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have a Map< String,ArrayList< BonusEntity > > Here key is EmpId of Employee and key will contains the List< BonusEntity >

BonusEntity will contains the following fields(All fields are String)

Empid
BonusDate
BonusAmount
Dept

I need to sort the ArrayList in Map based on the BonusDate descending order,Can anyone help Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please improve your question quality. You can find more tips in: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pages.

Comment: Entity class can implement Comparable 
implement Compare to as

    @Override
 public int compareTo(BonusEntity o) {
   
  return o.bonusdate.compareTo(this.bonusdate);
 }
and sort list using

     Collections.sort(list);
keep in mind that using string for holding date value will give you some unexpected results, use Date class instead of string

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that applies to your class `BonusEntity` and use it via the [`Collections.sort` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).

Comment: Alternatively, have `BonusEntity` implement `Comparable<BonusEntity>` then call `List.sort()`

Comment: Also possible, with `Comparable` you'll define one natural sort for the class. You can define as many `Comparator` as you can need/imagine.